# Memory violation in Android OpenGL GLES20 with glTexImage2D

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap, arrays, bytebuffer

I have a bitmap(which can be converted to a ByteBuffer). I want to upload all of its 6 faces by offsets to the GPU in OpenGL. When I do the following, the app crashes with OpenGL giving a memory violation.

Here `bitmap` is a byte array `byte[]`

```
for (int i=0 ; i<6 ; i++) {
      GLES20.glTexImage2D(
          GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i,
          0,
          GLES20.GL_RGBA,
          side,
          side,
          0,
          GLES20.GL_RGBA,
          GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
          ByteBuffer.wrap(bitmap, length / 6 * i, side * side * 4));
    }
```

But when I copy the array and then upload to the GPU like this(Here `bitmap` is of type `Bitmap`):

```
int numBytes = bitmap.getByteCount();
 ByteBuffer pixels = ByteBuffer.allocate(numBytes);
 bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(pixels);
 for (int i=0 ; i<6 ; i++) {
   Log.d("aakash", String.valueOf(numBytes / 6 * i));
   byte[] arr = Arrays.copyOfRange(pixels.array(), numBytes / 6 * i, numBytes / 6 * (i+1));
   GLES20.glTexImage2D(
       GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i,
       0,
       GLES20.GL_RGBA,
       bitmap.getWidth(),
       bitmap.getHeight() / 6,
       0,
       GLES20.GL_RGBA,
       GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
       ByteBuffer.wrap(arr));
 }
```

I get the cubemap correctly rendered.

What am I doing wrong in the first one? I want to avoid copying the array to upload parts of it to the GPU.

I can assure that the size and the mathematical calculations are correct.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid memory violation just replace

```
ByteBuffer pixels = ByteBuffer.allocate(numBytes);
```

with

```
ByteBuffer pixels = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(numBytes);
```

But you don't need ByteBuffer for simple side texture loading

```
loadSideTexture(context, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, R.raw.lake2_rt);
loadSideTexture(context, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X, R.raw.lake2_lf);

loadSideTexture(context, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y, R.raw.lake2_up);
loadSideTexture(context, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y, R.raw.lake2_dn);

loadSideTexture(context, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z, R.raw.lake2_bk);
loadSideTexture(context, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z, R.raw.lake2_ft);

private void loadSideTexture(Context context, int target, @RawRes int resID) {
    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getResources().openRawResource(resID));
    GLUtils.texImage2D(target, 0, bitmap, 0);
    bitmap.recycle();
}
```

Comment: For information: bitmap for cubemap texture need to be square, for example: 512 x 512